# Remove cs from created div

Tags: jquery

The following code is to display a div popup loader with a dimmed background during an async postback  in a .NET application. How do I remove the CSS class modal from 'body' in HideProgress()?

```
function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}

function HideProgress() {
    //alert('hideloading');
    document.getElementById("loading").onsubmit = null;
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("body").onsubmit = null;
    document.getElementById('body').style.display = 'none';
    //alert('done');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery elsewhere, the easiest way would be:

```
$('body').removeClass('modal');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `removeClass` function which removes a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(element).removeClass('modal');
```

where `element` refers to the actual element you want to remove the class from. e.g body

Comment: Thank you -- I think Paul beat you to the answer by a few seconds. I'd upvote, but I can't yet!